# Dynamically change 3D Center point in FlashCS4

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, flash-cs4

Using the new 3D features in CS4. I know you can change the 3d center point manually via the Transform panel, but does anyone know how to do this dynamically at runtime? (ie via code)

Answer (score 1):

i didn't know that too, but i did a quick google research and found [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html#projectionCenter)

i guess something like this will do the trick:

```
this.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = new Point(200,200);
```

Comment: more http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSCE716DAD-9364-464f-AFE9-8E578525AD54.html

Comment: This isn't the 3D center point though, just the vanishing point.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, I struggled with this, really pleased it was so simple to fix, though not so simple to find anything on. For centering I used it like this:

```
var centre:Point = new Point(stage.stageWidth / 2, stage.stageHeight / 2);
parent.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = centre;
```